# Show the year while listing files in the current directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

I am working on a Red Hat server. The commands `ls -l` or `ll` giving me the date and time in format `+"%b %-d %H:%M"`.

I want to list the files in a way where the year when each was file created would appear within the date.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 152):

You can use `man ls` and here you can find `--time-style` parameter. Or you can use:

`ls --full-time`.

Comment: Example for time style `ls -l --time-style=+%F`

Comment: For those who has already `ll` set as `ls -la` or something else, `ll --full-time` also work.

Comment: ls -l --time-style=long-iso shows cleaner output since doesn't print seconds/miliseconds

Answer (score 24):

`ls -l` will display month, day and **year** - *since*, according to BSD man page:
If the modification time of the file is more than 6 months in the past or future, then the **year** of the last modification is displayed in place of the hour and minute fields.

So, to make sure that **year** will always be shown, use:

`ls -l --time-style=long-iso` (GNU/Linux)

`ls -lT` will display complete time information in BSD (MacOS)

Comment: Your GNU/Linux variant should work on any GNU system, not only the one with Linux: `ls` comes from GNU coreutils there.

Comment: I think so, but not tested with another operating systems using GNU utils, only Linux :)

Comment: "If the modification time of the file is more than 6 months in the past or future, then the year of the last modification is displayed". This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Jan Marek's answer.... I've noticed you can get away with just:

> ls --full or ls --fu

which will do the same thing as `ls --full-time` as he described. Thanks Stéphane Chazelas. Now I type `ls --fu` everywhere. :)

Answer (score 6):

Since you asked for the year, `ls -lac` is an easy one to remember if, like me, you use `ls -la` all the time. The `c` gives you ctime which will display a year if it's not the current year or the hour and minute if it is.

Comment: I like this. A lot less noise in the output and only one letter to remember in the future.

Comment: This seems to change the behavior of `ls` to **date changed** rather than the default **date modified**.

Comment: `ls -l` displays date and time for dates that are in the past six months, and date and year for other dates.  ctime can be in the past six months just as much as mtime (modification date) can, so `ls -lac` can display times (instead of years) just as much as `ls -la` can.  Besides, as Mateen Ulhaq points out, `ls -lac` does not display the same dates that ``ls -la`` does. This answer is wrong.

Comment: This `-c` is actually a modifier for `-l` and `-t`. It changes the display style for the former, and sorting criteria for the latter. According to manual:
`−c  Use time of last modification of the file status information instead of last modification of the file itself for sorting (−t) or writing (−l).`

Answer (score 3):

**As an alternative to --full-time** and its iso-format you can also use the **--time-style** parameter appending the values you need:
`ls . -l --time-style=+%Y/%m/%d`
or +%y-%m-%d, maybe listing with -al instead (hidden files too)... That depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `busybox` (embedded distros, e.g. OpenWRT, LEDE), the switch you're looking for is `-e` for versions up to 1.26.2 and `--full-time` for 1.27.0 and above (see the [commit that changed it](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=194b2ebd2a0cfc1d27744dea10ef706975c61317)).

Comment: `-e` also works with Solaris `ls` and ast-open's, so it's actually closer to a standard than GNU's `--full-time`. A shame that busybox removed it in newer versions.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas didn't know that! Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

This will work on macOS Catalina and later:

```
ls -altT /path/to/some/dir
```